# Bluemix PHP JQuery license error

Tags: php, jquery, licensing, ibm-cloud

I am building a validation form within bluemix devOps. I am using jQuery and using php to check if there is already an existing email address in the database. With this code:

```
if(error == 0){
            $.post('validateEmail.php', {uEmail:email}, function(data){
                alert(data);
                if(parseInt(data) > 0){
                    $("input[name='email']").after("<div class='emailInput validationError'>"+span_error_start+errormsg[8]+span_error_end+"</div>").addClass("input_error");
                }
                else{
                    $(".myForm").submit();
                }
```

So when there is already an email in the database is gives me a 1 else it gives me a 0 when I alert the data i get this :

```
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
   You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.
  -->

with a 1 or a 0.
```

because it gives me this text my IF statement doesn`t work. Does someone know this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue, I was including a php wich for my database connection and that file had the text that was appearing. So i delete that text and the code worked!